# How did Naruto call Shikamaru and the others during Obito's fight?

Tags: naruto

**Alert: This post contains spoilers. If you are not up-to-date to Naruto's manga, don't read it.**

At chapter 651 of Naruto's manga, during the fight against Obito, Naruto called Shikamaru, Lee, Ino, Kiba and the others to join the fight and help him:

[image]

But what kind of jutsu did Naruto use to call them? Is he using the abilities of Yamanaka's clan or his own Kyuubi's chakra has this kind of power too?

Comment: is it just me or is the image broken?

Comment: @Vogel612 For me it's normal :/

Comment: Well now it works ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of the manga shows Sakura's thought's being relayed over to Ino. So if I were to draw an analogy, then I could safely say that the same is happening to Naruto and the others, like they are in a large broadcast room.

[image]

This part shows Shikamaru's thoughts being relayed over to the Second Hokage.

[image]

And finally this part shows Naruto and others conversing in their minds.

[image]

However it has been previously shown that the Yamanaka Clan's Mind Body Techinque can be used for a two way communication via thoughts, so this must be using Ino's technique and not Naruto's chakra.

Finally, Ino herself mentions that Naruto's thoughts and feeling's are being relayed over using her jutsu.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer *can be* the combination of the two:

- [Mind Body Transmission Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_Body_Transmission_Technique) from [Yamanaka](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yamanaka)
- And Naruto's Chakra present to them.

My theory is that Ino consistently connecting them using her Mind Body Transmission Technique from the start. And since they have Naruto's chakra, they even share the feeling not just the picture (or the message) they want to convey to everyone. Also I remember on Chapter 645, Naruto is in combined Sage and Kyubbi mode. Naruto's *Biju mode* is so powerful that he can sense the "dark feeling/hatred" from something or someone.

Comment: it isn't naruto's sage mode chakra that enables him to sense "Dark feeling" rather it is his Biju mode that does so. That is why he could sense Kisame inside of samehada after he entered the biju mode. It has been mentioned in that chapter that his biju mode enables him to do so.

Comment: Sorry. I realized that when I remember the time he tries to re seal the kyubi. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: i do agree with you, it must be a combination of both Ino's Mind Body Transmission and Naruto's sharing of chakra.

Answer (score 5):

Recall when Naruto's feelings were relayed to everyone that he was sharing chakra with? That is his method of communication. Sharing the kyuubi chakra and transferring it to other shinobi establishes a link that lets them share thoughts with each other.

Comment: and half the time he does it subconsciously. :P